# How do we justify the integration of $f'(x)=\arcsin'{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}x^{2k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the function $f(x)=\arcsin{(x)}$ and the task of finding the Taylor series at $0$ for this function.

We have  $$f'(x)=\arcsin'{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Let $g(x)=(1+x)^\alpha$. Then, for $|x|<1$ and any $\alpha$,

$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} x^k$$

That is, $g$ can be represented as an infinite series, the binomial series.

Note that this infinite series is a convergent power series centered at $0$. Hence, it must be the Taylor series of $g$ at $0$.

Using this fact we can show that for $|x|<1$,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}x^{2k}$$

Thus, for $|x|<1$,

$$f'(x)=\arcsin'{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}x^{2k}$$

If we integrate we obtain the result

$$f(x)=\arcsin{(x)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Which, if true, means we have another convergent power series centered at $0$ so we have found the desired Taylor series of $\arcsin$ at $0$.

**My question is**: how do we justify this integration step?

If we prove that the sequence of functions

$$\{f_n'\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{-1/2}{k}x^{2k}\right\}$$

converges uniformly to $\arcsin'$ on some interval, then I know of a theorem that says that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n' =\int_a^b \arcsin'$$

This seems like it might involve a lot of calculations. Nonetheless, would it be a valid justification?

We could also just use the fact that $\arcsin'$ is continuous and use the first fundamental theorem of calculus.

Is this a correct justification?

Comment: If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ over $[a,b]$ then $\Big|\int_{[a,b]}f_n-f\Big|\leq\int_{[a,b]}|f_n-f|\leq\|f-f_n\|_u(b-a)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. You already proved before that $(1+x)^c=\sum_n\binom{c}{n}x^n$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and convergence absolutely and uniformly on any compact subinterval of $(-1,1)$. you problem then becomes easy substitute $x by x^2$ and $c=-1/2$.

Answer (score 4):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\left|\binom{-\frac12}n\right|=\left|(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right|<1,$$and therefore the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}nx^n$ is at least $1$ (it turns out that it is equal to $1$). So, the series converge uniformly on any interval $[-a,a]$, when $a\in(0,1)$, and this uniform convergence justifies the integration step.

Comment: Is the use of the first fundamental theorem of calculus also a justification?

Comment: You need to to deduce that$$\arcsin(x)=\int_0^x\arcsin'(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}kt^k\,\mathrm dt,$$but it doesn't explain why is it that we have$$\int_0^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}kt^k\,\mathrm dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^x\binom{-1/2}kt^k\,\mathrm dt.$$